# In Big-O notation, do we take the limit of a series's terms as we approach infinity, or evaluate the term at infinity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

For example, say we had a function:

$$f(x)=x+2x^2+3x^3+4x^4+...\text{ for } x\geq1$$

Then can we write:

$$f(x)=O(x) \text{ as } x\rightarrow1$$

since the value of $f(x)$ at $x=1$ is $-1/12$? Or do we argue that the limit of the function is $\infty$, thererefore there is no bounding term?

Comment: "infiniteth term"? What in the world is that?

Comment: What? The *infinitieth* coefficient is negative? Even if it existed, I'd have bet it would be positive.

Comment: @horse Noooooooo no no no no no. Not this $-1/12$ nonsense again. $\infty$ is not $-1/12$. They're unrelated things. Big $O$ is about bounding functions. There is no last coefficient so in other words, the coefficient at $\infty$ is $\infty$ but that doesn't mean you can manipulate it like a real number.

Comment: I didn't say that $\infty=-1/12$, I said that $\sum_1^\infty n=-1/12$, which is clearly true.

Comment: @horse No, it clearly *is not true* ... in standard mathematics. You can do some tricks with the Riemann z- functions and etc., as if that infinite series sum is $\;-\frac1{12}\;$ , but seriously: it is **not** a mathematical equality but a fictional, funny trick. Don't believe everything you read/hear/see in the web.

Comment: @Don It isn't just the zeta-function, you can also do the same thing by adding an exponentially decreasing regulator $e^{-\epsilon n}$ to each term to make it convergent and taking the limit $\epsilon\rightarrow0$.

Comment: @horse What? I've no idea what that means in this context, but it doesn't really matter: the series $\;\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n\;$ diverges big time and its sum, under the standard rules, laws and definitions in analysis and mathematics, is by no means finite, and even less $\;-\frac1{12}\;$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your mathematical question about the big "O" notation:

$$f(x)=\mathcal O(x)\;\;\text{as}\;\;x\to1\iff \lim\sup_{x\to1}\left|\frac{f(x)}x\right|<\infty\iff$$

$$\iff\lim\sup_{x\to1}(1+2x+3x^2+\ldots)<\infty\;,\;\;\text{and this is clearly false}.$$

under the usual assumptions and definition in mathematics.

Comment: Just as an aside, but where is the function bounded (by the normal def. of summation)? Clearly $f(0)=0$ but $f(1)=\infty$ so where in $(0,1)$ does the function become unbounded? Or is it only bounded at $0$ and I'm being stupid? Edit: ignoring the stipulation by OP that $x\geq1$

Comment: Do you mean *where* $\;f\;$ *is bounded*? Well, this function's actually$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n$$It's easy to see this power series' convergence radius is $\;1\;$ , so it defines a funcion whenever $\;|x|<1\;$, and in fact$$f(x)=x\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}=x\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\right)'=x\left(\frac1{1-x}\right)'\ldots\text{and etc.}$$

Comment: Of course you're right. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

To evaluate the function, multiply it by $(1-x)$ to get

$$\begin{align}
(1-x)f(x)=&(1-x)(x+2x^2+3x^3+\dots)\\
(1)\qquad=&1(x+2x^2+3x^3+\dots)-x(x+2x^2+3x^3+\dots)\\
(2)\qquad=&(x+2x^2+3x^3+\dots)-(x^2+2x^3+3x^4+\dots)\\
(3)\qquad=&x+(2-1)x^2+(3-2)x^3+\dots\\
(4)\qquad=&x+x^2+x^3+\dots\\
(5)\qquad=&\frac x{1-x}
\end{align}$$

$(1):$ distribute the $(1-x)$.

$(2):$ distribute the $x$ on the second series.

$(3):$ combine like terms.

$(4):$ calculate like terms.

$(5):$ evaluate geometric series.

$$(1-x)f(x)=\frac x{1-x}$$

$$f(x)=\frac x{(1-x)^2}$$

So even if you could have the function defined for $|x|\ge1$, $f(1)$ still wouldn't exist and we wouldn't have the silly $f(1)=-1/12$ thing.

Now, there are values you can pull out the function for $x=1$, but they do not relate to $-1/12$ nor do they have any meaning here.  For example, the residue of the function at $x=1$ is given by $1$ (but who cares?)